# Toggle between styles, like button for "bold text" active/inactive

Tags: jquery, editor

I'm building an editor and have a function to make text bold. But how do I toggle the function so, if I mark the text and click the button "bold" and then click it again to remove the bold style?

Consider that I have the variable selectedID from when I "select" the element.

HTML:

```
 <button id='addBold'>Bold</button>
```

Jquery:

```
        $("#addBold").on('click', function () {
    $("#container > #"+selectedID).css("font-weight", "bold");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method which adds a class to the element or removes it if it has it allready.

**jQuery**

```
$("#addBold").on('click', function () {
    $("#container > #"+selectedID).toggleClass("boldText");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.boldText {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: No problem! Btw, would this be possible? `if ($(this).hasClass('boldText')) {
  $('#addBold').addClass('active')
  }`

Comment: It looks valid jQuery code, but I cannot say more without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Okey, I think I figure it out! Thanks anyway! :)